# Sample size to estimate mean of the exponential of Gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, sample-size

What sample size should I take in order to estimate the mean of the exponential of normal distribution?

I use Matlab to make an approximation:

```
r = normrnd(0,5, 1,10^7); % generate 10 million sample, mu=0, sigma=5
mean(exp(r)) % gives 1.5493e+05
exp(0+5^2/2) % real expected value is 2.6834e+05
```

As can be seen the error is huge.

Comment: It depends on which estimator you use and how you measure accuracy. Choose an estimator that will minimise your loss function

Comment: @Glen_b , can you be more specific? What estimator are you talking about? The simple difference is huge.

Comment: Naturally, the mse of any estimator would be large. The big question is whether mse even makes sense here.

Comment: @Glen_b, I want to estimate the size of a sample, so the value is reasonably close to the true value.

Comment: No doubt you're of the opinion that this is sufficiently precise information. I have tried to convey that it isn't. Once you have a relevant measure of *close* that's suitable to your purpose, you can always use simulation to reasonably quickly home in on a sample size that achieves it with at least a given probability; you don't need to be able to do the algebra. "Lets try n=100. Okay, that's way too small. What about n=10000? Okay, that's too big. What about 1000? A little too small. But let's interpolate in $n^\frac12$ from there. Okay, looks like 3200 is the right ballpark..." etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different methods you can use to estimate how big $n$ needs to be so that your empirical estimate is close to the true answer. I am going to use the simplest method which results in the largest value of $n$. Generally, you can do a lot better, but then the derivation gets a lot more involved.

Let $X\sim \textbf{Normal}(0,5^2)$ and set $Y = e^X$. We can calculate that $\mathbf{E}(Y) = e^{5^2/2}$. We can also calculate (I used WolframAlpha) that $\mathbf{Var}(Y) = e^{50} - e^{25}$.

Assume that $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are independent samples having the same distribution as $Y$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By the Law of Large Numbers we have that,
$$ P \left( \left| \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{n} - e^{5^2/2} \right| > \varepsilon \right) \leq \frac{\mathbf{Var}(Y)}{n\varepsilon}$$
For instance if $\varepsilon = 1$, and we want $90\%$ confidence that we are within $1$ of the true answer then we need to choose $n$ in order to satisfy,
$$ \frac{e^{50} - e^{25}}{n} < 0.1 $$
If we solve for $n$ we find that $n$ should be around $5.2\times 10^{22}$.

But, keep in mind, this is the absolute most basic crude estimate. We should be able to improve upon this either by using CLT or manipulating Chernoff bounds.

Comment: Could you show how to use the Chernoff bounds?